# Бэкап только новых данных MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных, резервное-копирование, autoincrement

Есть например таблица с 10 милионов записей.

Бэкап делаем раз в неделю.
За неделю допустим накопились ещё 5 милионов записей.

Как на сделать бэкап только новым данным?
В таблице есть `auto-increment`.

Comment: *Бэкап делаем раз в неделю.* как именно? *Как на сделать бэкап только новым данным?* Скопировать их во временную БД...

Comment: Сервер генерирует .sql файл и добавляет его в архив.

Comment: *Сервер генерирует .sql файл* Вот то есть сам, без команд, по собственной инициативе? не, ну надо же думать, прежде чем отвечать...

Comment: конечно с командой

Comment: вот команда: `/usr/local/vesta/bin/v-backup-user admin yes`

Comment: Надо понимать, это запускается некий скрипт, который запускает некую команду, собственно выполняющую резервное копирование... И какую же?

Comment: команда есть выше

Comment: Вот список штатных программ, устанавливаемых MySQL: [Overview of MySQL Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/programs-overview.html). Ткните пальцем, где там хоть что-то говорится про некую `v-backup-user`.

Comment: вижу что нету, так я не говорю что данная команда нужна, нужно по другому сделать резервное копирование (описал в вопросе), но как такое сделать не знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможное решение.

1a. Выполняется дамп структуры БД, без данных. Например, с помощью утилиты [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html), запускаемой с ключом [--no-data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data).

1b. Выполняется полное резервное копирование данных таблиц, каждой таблицы отдельно, с помощью SQL-запроса [SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html).

либо

1. Выполняется дамп структуры БД, вместе с данными. Например, с помощью утилиты [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html)

В дальнейшем

2. Выполняется инкрементное резервное копирование данных таблиц, каждой таблицы отдельно, с помощью SQL-запроса [SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html). Отбор копируемых данных выполняется в секции `WHERE` запроса - по значению штампа времени изменения записи либо по значению синтетического автоинкрементного ключа. Сведения о штампе времени или автоинкременте для копированных ранее записей для каждой таблицы можно хранить в служебной таблице той же или служебной БД либо вовне.

Comment: Чтобы это работало на автомате, нужно чтобы сисадмин сделал определёную службу? Или можно и на PHP написать скрипт который будет выполняться через CRON?

Comment: Нет. У MySQL имеется собственный планировщик, который и нужно использовать. См. [CREATE EVENT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html). Ну а скрипт (хранимую процедуру) резервного копирования (и восстановления!), само собой, придётся создать. И не забыть включить планировщик. И при создании процедуры восстановления - проконтролировать порядок загрузки данных в таблицы, чтобы не получить ошибку отсутствия референсов.